# How to make a file save dialog from Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, file, download

Now the file can be downloaded from the Spring controller but there is no dialog and the file is directly saved to the download folder of the browser. I would like a file dialog that asks the user for which folder to save in. How can it be done? The code is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView export(HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        String str = "sep=\t\n"; // tells excel what the delimiter character should be
        Iterator<Individual> iterator = customerAccountService.getAllIndividuals().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Individual individual = iterator.next();
            str = str + individual.getId() + "\t" +individual.getIndividualName().getName() + "\t" + individual.getAddress().getStreetName() + "\n";
        }
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.setContentType("application/xls");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=Users-export.csv");
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //logger.info("Error writing file to output stream. Filename was '" + fileName + "'");
        throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(ViewName.MENU);
    modelAndView.addObject(ObjectName.ADD_FORM, new LoginForm());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that your Spring web application is meant to be an HTTP compliant application. HTTP is a request-response protocol. The client sends a request and the server sends a response.

In your case the response will look like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Users-export.csv
Content-Type: application/xls
Content-Length: XYZ

<bytes goes here>
```

Your client, a browser, will receive this and do whatever it chooses with it. You should check your browser settings and enable a `Save As...` prompt.

---

There is no way to force a browser prompt from a web application.